# Foreground service problem when message is received on socket.io chat

Tags: android, android-fragments, socket.io, android-service, foreground-service

App run with foreground service and device stay connected, but when a message is sent from other client, the app unfortunately stops. and i get that error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: EventThread
    Process: com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat, PID: 6693
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)'
 on a null object reference
  at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat.MainFragment$6.call(MainFragment.java:339)
```

This is code in my Fragment class, that logcat give me causing the error.

```
    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    String username;
                    String message;
                    try {
                        username = data.getString("username");
                        message = data.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }

                    removeTyping(username);
                    addMessage(username, message);
                    setNotificationMessage(message, username);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems getActivity() returns you a null object because that activity is no longer visible.

You could use a Handler associated with the main UI thread:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {...);
```

Still I don't think UI thread is necessary there, just call a normal thread.